# Trouble with multiple mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble using multiple queries within one php file. The code that I am trying to create would ideally create multiple html drop down menus populated with data from separate tables. My code is as follows:

```
 echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'      action='http://www.vgiver.com/uploadpicture1.php' name='Giftgiver'>";
  $Wrap= @mysql_query("select Wrap_ID, Picture_Link from tbl_Wrap"); 
 print "<p> Select a Wrapping Paper: \n";
 print "<Select name=\"Wrap_ID\">\n";

 while ($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($Wrap)){
  $Wrap_ID=$row2['Wrap_ID'];
  $Wrap_Picture =$row2['Picture_Link'];
    print "<option value=$Wrap_ID>$Wrap_Picture \n";
  }

 $result= @mysql_query("select Friend_ID, tbl_Friends.Name from tbl_Friends inner join     tbl_Users on tbl_Friends.Access_ID=tbl_Users.Access_ID where tbl_Friends.Access_ID =     $myuserid"); 
  $Wrap= @mysql_query("select Wrap_ID, Picture_Link from tbl_Wrap"); 
print "<p> Select a Friend: \n";
 print "<Select name=\"Friend_ID\">\n"; 

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $Friend_ID=$row['Friend_ID'];
  $Name =$row['Name'];
  print "<option value=$Friend_ID>$Name \n";
  }
```

However, as it is now, this code will create a selection box for only one set of data. It does not matter which query I do first, it will either display a drop down menu for a friend's list, or a drop down menu for my wrapping paper, but it will not display both.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten ending `<select>`, `<p>`, `<option>` tag.
It should looks like:

```
 <?php

  echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'      action='http://www.vgiver.com/uploadpicture1.php' name='Giftgiver'>";
  $Wrap = @mysql_query("select Wrap_ID, Picture_Link from tbl_Wrap");
  print "<p> Select a Wrapping Paper:</p> \n";
  print "<Select name=\"Wrap_ID\">\n";

  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Wrap)) {
        $Wrap_ID = $row2['Wrap_ID'];
        $Wrap_Picture = $row2['Picture_Link'];
        print "<option value=$Wrap_ID>$Wrap_Picture </option>\n";
  }
  echo '</select>';

  $result = @mysql_query("select Friend_ID, tbl_Friends.Name from tbl_Friends inner join     tbl_Users on tbl_Friends.Access_ID=tbl_Users.Access_ID where tbl_Friends.Access_ID =     $myuserid");
  $Wrap = @mysql_query("select Wrap_ID, Picture_Link from tbl_Wrap");
  print "<p> Select a Friend: </p>\n";
  print "<Select name=\"Friend_ID\">\n";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $Friend_ID = $row['Friend_ID'];
        $Name = $row['Name'];
        print "<option value=$Friend_ID>$Name </option>\n";
  }
  echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Not enough... </option> and </p> tags are also missing.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Thanks. I really appreciate downvoters like you, commented, and even switched your vote to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

After each of your while loops you need to end the `<select>` tag:

```
print "<select name=\"Wrap_ID\">\n";

while ($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($Wrap)){
  $Wrap_ID=$row2['Wrap_ID'];
  $Wrap_Picture =$row2['Picture_Link'];
  print "<option value=$Wrap_ID>$Wrap_Picture</option> \n";
}

print '</select>';
```

You should also end your `<option>` tags properly like in the example above

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `select`'s and your `option`'s:

```
 print "<p> Select a Wrapping Paper: \n";
 print "<Select name=\"Wrap_ID\">\n";

 while ($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($Wrap)){
  $Wrap_ID=$row2['Wrap_ID'];
  $Wrap_Picture =$row2['Picture_Link'];
    print "<option value=$Wrap_ID>$Wrap_Picture</option>\n";
  }
 print "</select>"; //<-------add this
```

EDIT:

Also your paragraph. HTML requires tags to be closed:

```
<tag>content</tag>
```

So you would have:

```
 print "<p> Select a Wrapping Paper: </p> \n";
```

instead of:

```
 print "<p> Select a Wrapping Paper: \n";
```

Your full code should be:

```
 echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'      action='http://www.vgiver.com/uploadpicture1.php' name='Giftgiver'>";
  $Wrap= @mysql_query("select Wrap_ID, Picture_Link from tbl_Wrap"); 
 print "<p> Select a Wrapping Paper:</p> \n";
 print "<Select name=\"Wrap_ID\">\n";

 while ($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($Wrap)){
  $Wrap_ID=$row2['Wrap_ID'];
  $Wrap_Picture =$row2['Picture_Link'];
    print "<option value=$Wrap_ID>$Wrap_Picture</option> \n";
  }
 print "</select>";

 $result= @mysql_query("select Friend_ID, tbl_Friends.Name from tbl_Friends inner join     tbl_Users on tbl_Friends.Access_ID=tbl_Users.Access_ID where tbl_Friends.Access_ID =     $myuserid"); 
  $Wrap= @mysql_query("select Wrap_ID, Picture_Link from tbl_Wrap"); 
print "<p> Select a Friend: </p> \n";
 print "<Select name=\"Friend_ID\">\n"; 

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $Friend_ID=$row['Friend_ID'];
  $Name =$row['Name'];
  print "<option value=$Friend_ID>$Name</option> \n";
  }
print "</select>";
```

**Bonus hints:**

Use single quotes instead of double quotes when you don't need to do parsing for variables as it is faster.

Use `echo` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't close your `<selects>`. The second set of data is there, but HTML ignores it. try viewing the source of your file you'll see.